# C# How to notify other classes with a single timer?

Tags: c#, timer, delegates

I am trying to make a global timer where everything that needs to be notified after certain time has passed.

For instance, in a game, there would be buffs and attack cool down timers and item cool down and much more.

Managing them separately is fine, but how would I make them all to run on same timer?

I was tried using SortedList with a float as key and a delegate as value to be simply invoked when time is up, but I cant seem to manage it. Tried delegate with Generic parameter but I can't put that into a sorted list.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can point out 2 options:

1. Create an interface like `TimerControlled` (all names can be changed) With a method `TimerTick(whatever arguments you need)` (and others if needed) , which implements your timer tick logic for that class. Implement the interface the on each class that uses timer dependent mechanics. Finally on your base (logic) class add all of your `TimerControlled` object to an array (of `TimerControlled`) which will allow you to cycle through that array and call TimerTick methods of those object with 2 lines of code.

Interface:

```
interface TimerControlled
{
   void TimerTick();
}
```

Implement it in each of your classes:

```
public class YourClass: TimerControlled{
   ....
   public void TimerTick(){
      advanceCooldown();
      advanceBuffTimers();
   }
}
```

finally add your classes to a list of `TimerControlled`:

```
class YourLogicClass{
   List<YourClass> characters= new List<YourClass>();
   private timer;
   List<TimerControlled> timerControlledObjects = new List<TimerControlled>();
   ...
   public void Initialize(){
      ... //your code, character creation and such
      foreach(YourClass character in characters){ //do the same with all objects that have TimerControlled interface implemented
         timerControlledObjects.add(character);
      }
      timer = new Timer();
      timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timerTick)
      timer.Start();

   } 

   public void timerTick(Object sender, EventArgs e){
      foreach(TimerControlled timerControlledObject in timerControlObjects){
         timerControlledObject.TimerTick();
      }
   }

}
```

2. (not a very good option in the long run) Static timer in a static class, like `Global.timer`, which will mean only 1 instance of that timer will exist. Then attach an event handler to timer from each relevant class to handle timer ticks.

Code:

```
public static class Global{
//I usually create such class for global settings
   public static Timer timer= new Timer();
}



class YourLogicClass{
   public void Initialize(){
       ... 
       Global.timer.Start();
   }
}

class YourClass{

   public YourClass(){
      Global.timer.tick += new EventHandler(timerTick);
   }


   private void timerTick(Object sender,EventArgs e){
      advanceCooldowns();
      advanceBuffTimers();
   }
}
```

Keep in mind that I've written the code off the top of my head, so some syntax errors might be there, but the logic is right.

If you have further questions regarding the answer ask away.

Comment: I think I need to explain a bit more.

Comment: I have a global timer that accepts requests to notify at a certain time. 

I also have a buff manager for each character that holds buff data. It certainly requires time check to remove buffs wouldn't it? So buff manager requests a buff to be enlisted on timer and notified when it ends. 

The trouble is, I also wish to have item cooldown, attack cool down, skill cool down and any other things that requires time check or notifications.

Comment: The way I would approach it is not by notifying when cooldown/buff timer reaches the goal, but by recording time left and depleting that time tick by tick, and when time runs out activate any sort of logic to re-enable item/remove buff etc. That way all the logic stays within the relevant class and all that timer does is informs your classes of each tick.

Comment: That would be a way. However, wouldn't doing a lot of float calculations per tick be too costly?

Comment: If you think about it, you'd be doing the exact same thing regardless of where you put the logic. Either way you will keep adding/subtracting and checking if the timer is at your goal. I mean even if you notify all of your individual Buff Managers from your logic class, the logic class still has to keep track of when to notify each manager and either have reference of when the timer was placed and when to call it or an individual variable for each buff that would work similar to what i described in comment before.

Comment: You can reduce the number of calculations (using a single timeline and having variables that point to specific time it should activate on for instance currentTime+3sec), but unless you have ridiculous amounts of timers to notify it the processing cost reduction probably won't pay off.

Comment: Well, that is why I'm trying this ridiculous task. I'm trying to cram them into a sorted list so that I dont have to check all of them. If they are sorted in nearest time (or smallest end time), I can notify elements until I meet an element whose time is larger than current time. 


Do you see my point? Provided that there aren't too many in and out operations, I speculate that this is way faster than maintaining a lot of timers or calculating all ticks.

Comment: At any rate, you wanted to know how to notify a list, Interface implementation is your best bet. As for efficiency, it will greatly depend on numbers of active timer data and how many ticks an average timer has.
Simple and minimal option is a variable set to N seconds and subtract until zero. A better option is a time-line with timers on specific time. Anything beyond that depends too much on usage (and will probably give performance boost less than you can perceive with a few thousands of active timers.
Best of luck on your project.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Though I can't seem to make it just the way I wanted using delegates, but by the use of tuple, I managed to get it work practically the same way. By returning unique number when enlisting and sending messages at the end to that class with that unique number as variable, I can now use global timer.